# Couting the number of specific values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

im using the below code to test if some conditions are met and then i want to count the number of times each condition is met so i can do some further calculations.

```
for x = 1:35

    N = csvread(fullpath1, 1);  

    Resultgenerated = N(x,1);
    Resultgiven= N(x,2);

    outcome1 = [];
    outcome2 = [];

    if (Resultgenerated >= 1) && (Resultgiven  >= 1)
        outcome1 = 1; %true positive
    elseif (Resultgenerated <= 0) && (Resultgiven >= 1)
    outcome1 = 2; %'False Positive';
    end
    if (Resultgenerated <= 0) && (Resultgiven <= 0)
        outcome1 = 3; %'True Negative';
    elseif (Resultgenerated >= 1) && (Resultgiven <= 0)
        outcome1 = 4; %'False Negative';
    end

    hout{x} = outcome1;
end 
sum(hout(:) == 4)
```

i'm getting the error

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in potential_compare (line 132)
sum(hout(:) == 4)
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be brilliant!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use cells if you don't have to.  For your case you are storing the result `outcome1` alone.

```
hout = zeros(1,35);
for x = 1:35
% bunch of stuff
hout(x) = outcome1;
end
sum(hout == 4)
```

Comment: @KyleMoffett Remember to accept an answer if it completely solved your needs. Thanks!